# How to pass Array List as an Argument to the Fragment and Retrieve it

Tags: android, android-fragments, arguments

I'm trying to pass `ArrayList<DataField>` as an argument to the fragment but can't understand which method should I use.

I'm using bundle to send the argument to the Fragment like this

```
bundle.putSerializable(Constants.ARRAY_DATA, dataArray);
```

and when I try to get the argument in the Fragment using

```
getArguments().getSerializable(Constants.ARRAY_DATA)
```

I'm getting an error

> Incompatible types. Required: java.util.ArrayList
>    Found:
>   java.io.Serializable"

```
getArguments().getParcelable(Constants.ARRAY_DATA);
```

isn't showing any error but

```
bundle.putParcelable(Constants.ARRAY_DATA, dataArray);
```

is showing an error

> Wrong 2nd argument type.  Found:
>   'java.util.ArrayList',
>   required: 'android.os.Parcelable'

putParcelable
(String,
android.os.Parcelable)
in Bundle cannot be applied
to
(String,
java.util.ArrayList)

Which method should I use to send Array List of Custom Data Field through the bundle and retreive it using arguments?

Comment: does `DataField` implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: No. The `DataField` class doesn't implement anything. It has only getters & setters.

Comment: you might want to read the documentation about it then

Comment: I already did. One can pass Integer array list using `getIntegerArrayList()`, `putIntegerArrayList()`, String array list using `putStringArrayList()`, `getStringArrayList()', Char sequence using `putCharSequenceArrayList()`, `getCharSequenceArrayList()`. But can't find the exact solution for my problem. I've read multiple questions on SO too.

Comment: Let your datafield implement parcelable for a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing primitive data types through bundles is easy as they have pre defined methods. Simply, put the data with unique key and send it to another activity or fragment. But if the user wants to send custom objects through bundles or intents, Data field class should implement Parcelable interface.

You can also use Serializable, Parceler, GSON ... Out of all Parcelable is the fastest way of writing and reading objects.

Below we will see an implementation of **Parcelable** and finally how to pass the data using it.

**Step 1:** Implement the DataField Class with **Parcelable**

```
public class DataField implements Parcelable {
```

**Step 2:** Use the `parcel` object inside the `writeToParcel` method to save all the instance variables in the DataField class.

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(itemName);
    parcel.writeString(itemUrl);
}
```

**Step 3:** Documentation says

> Classes implementing the Parcelable interface must also have a
>   non-null static field called CREATOR of a type that implements the
>   Parcelable.Creator interface.

So, we need to implement this interface to read the Parcelable.

```
public static final Creator<DataField> CREATOR = new Creator<DataField>() {
    @Override
    public DataField createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new DataField(in);
    }

    @Override
    public DataField[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DataField[size];
    }
};
```

**Step 4:** Take a look at the return statement in the `createFromParcel` method. We have constructor (`DataField(in)`) that we haven't defined earlier in the class. Now, we are going to implement this constructor and also restore all the data that we've saved earlier.

```
private DataField(Parcel in) {
    itemName = in.readString();
    itemUrl = in.readString();
}
```

**Make sure you are reading all the variables in the same order. Otherwise, you'll end up storing wrong values inside wrong variables.**

**Step 5:** Back in the activity, Simply use

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList(Constants.ARRAY_DATA, dataArray);
```

**Step 6:** Inside the fragment, use the arguments and `getParcelableArrayList` method to get the data array

```
dataArray = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(Constants.ARRAY_DATA);
```

You can use the same procedure to pass the `ArrayList<DataField>` through intents and `putParcelableArrayList`, `getParcelableArrayList`.